# Why does the Macbook Pro Unibody crash on hibernate under Windows?

Tags: mac, crash, boot-camp

My late 2008, Macbook Pro Unibody machine has a number of ugly flaws that rear their head under Windows (Bootcamp):

1. Crash 9 out of 10 times on Hibernate
2. Audio stuttering (already have the latest drivers for everything from Microsoft)
3. Trackpad use causing crashes

Sadly, this undesirable behavior happens under both Vista and Win7RC. Has anyone had any luck solving these issues? My guess is that they are mostly driver related, but I just can not resolve them.

Before you ask, yes I've binged and tried all the usual approaches, installing BootCamp 2.1, etc.

Also, it might be useful to know that I'm currently on Win7RC 64-bit

Comment: Had the same problem on my white MacBook.  It has slowly weaned me off Windows development and onto MacOS.

Comment: If I go to the Start Menu and manually click Hibernate, it hibernates just fine. I only have problems with crashing when I shut the lid.

I have my power settings set so that the shut lid action is hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the win7 64bit hibernate bug everywhere except in VMs. I just turned off hibernate. I'm hoping it will be fixed before final release, but this seems to happen on all hardware.

These are all most certainly driver issues. You might look around for some beta drivers, or maybe try downgrading to older version drivers. Sadly there is only one way to find out ... try and see.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to check is that the mac is not running too hot.

I "fixed" one mac crashing in a multitude of ways by installing [smcFanControl](http://www.eidac.de/?cat=40) and tweaking up minimum fan speeds by about 15%.

Comment: use smcFanControl2, by the way. big fan.

Comment: I'm monitoring my temperature on Windows using SpeedFan. Its around 60C during Idle, yet all of those issues persist.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have load all the windows drivers from the Mac OSX installation disc. Does this happens when you you use Parallelz or VM fusion?

Comment: No. Does not happen in Parallels or Fusion. Probably because they both run simulated hardware, for which Windows can pick up the correct drivers. Its the Apple-supplied drivers that are the problem here